# How to replace #site-title with a RESIZABLE image?

Tags: css, wordpress-theming, image-resizing

I am able to replace the `#site-title` text [with a fixed-size image](http://bentcorner.com/replacing-wordpress-twenty-eleven-site-title-with-an-image/), no problem.

But now I would like to make it resize automatically based on the browser's size, just like WordPresse's header in Twenty Eleven.

FireBug tells me that the CSS responsible for that is:

```
#branding img {
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: -7px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

But when I try copying this to the site-title:

```
 #site-title {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 100%;  /* 980px;  width of the image file. */
    height: auto; /* 128px;  height of the image file. */

    margin: 0px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0em 0 0;
    background: url(images/header.png) white no-repeat;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

This doesn't really work: The site-title image stays the same original size.

Is there something else I need to do to create the "resizable magic" functionality that the new WordPress has?

Comment: This is a CSS question, not a wordpress question.

Comment: @m0r7if3r Are you sure? As you can see from my post, I did try [the CSS method](http://allaboutbasic.com/2011/06/15/wordpress-com-theme-twenty-eleven-css-style-sheet-modification-change-site-titledescriptionpost-titlecommentsmenussidebar-and-more/), but it appears that an additional trick is needed, which is very WordPress-specific. Perhaps something in `functions.php`?

Comment: It's just [CSS3 media queries](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries), there's nothing wordpress is doing. If you look at the end of style.css for twentyeleven you'll see it.

Comment: This *is* a CSS question and a CSS issue. Migrating to Stack Overflow where you can get some better answers...

Comment: OK thanks. I am still struggling with this issue since both the `#site-title` image and the header images are under the `#branding img` in the WordPress `Twenty Eleven` theme. But only the header image resizes. I wonder why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the image to resize, the parent element has to be resizable. If you take the twenty-eleven theme, the `#page` element doesn't have a `width` though it has a max-width. Then `width:100%` for the image will make it resize according to the browser width.

Comment: Thanks (+1) but how do I apply this to the site-title's image? Its image is in a `background: url` attribute, not in an `img` attribute like the header's.

Comment: Use `background-size:cover` in CSS. It will make the background image scale to the size of the element. But for older (<9) IE, you have to use proprietary filters. See http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: Thanks +1 again. That's a great tip, but when I tried it I didn't get the expected result: If I use it in conjunction with `background-attachment: scroll` it doesn't scale at all, and when I use it with `background-attachment: fixed` it [scales](http://whereswalden.com/files/mozilla/background-size/page-cover.html), but it scales to the size of the entire browser page size, not just the `#site-title` element.

Comment: Try `background-size:100% 100%` which works fine for me. `background-size:cover` is supposed to be an alias for that, but not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: You are a genius (+1 again). `background-size:100% 100%` worked! Actually it only scaled the width and kept height fixed, but `background-size:100%` (without the 2nd value) made height automatically scale to track aspect ratio, as explained [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp). BTW, w3schools.com claims they are not aliases: `cover` refers to **content area** whereas percentage refers to **parent element**. Long live subtleties! :)